# Why copy post data in Django instead of working with it directly?

Tags: python, django

Django code samples involving post data often shows code similar to this:

```
if request.method == "POST":
   post = request.POST.copy()
   #do stuff with post data
```

Is there a reason for copying the post data instead of working with it directly?

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12611345/django-why-is-the-request-post-object-immutable

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think it is because `request.POST` itself is defined immutable. If you want a version you can actually change (mutability), you need a copy of the data to work with.

See [this link](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects) (request.POST is a QueryDict instance).

---

> #### [class QueryDict](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects)
>
> `QueryDict` instances are immutable, unless you create a `copy()` of them. That means you can’t change attributes of `request.POST` and `request.GET` directly.

Comment: +1: And it *must* be immutable so that it can be built lazily.  The copy forces getting all the POST data.  Until the copy, it may not all be fetched.  Further, for a multi-threaded WSGI server to work reasonably well, it's helpful if this is immutable.