# django - why is the request.POST object immutable?

Tags: django, post

As the title asks, why did the Django guys decide to implement the request.POST object with a querydict (which, of course, in turn, makes the whole thing immutable?)

I know you can *mutify* it by making a copy of the post data

```
post = request.POST.copy()
```

but why do this? Surely it would be simpler just to allow the thing to be mutable anyway? Or is it being used for some other reason too which might cause issue?

Comment: Why do you want it to be mutable? You can take the data from it and use/modify it in your view. By adding data to it, you could create the impression that `request.POST` has been submitted with more data than it actually has been.

Comment: It isn't that I *want* it to be mutable. No more than, say, I'd want ice cream to be cold. In the case of ice cream though, if it *isn't* cold it melts and then you get scolded for making a big ol' mess. But with the request.POST object... I mean, if I'm going to screw up my code, I'm going to screw it up. I wasn't aware there was an endemic of developers adding data to POST objects and Causing Problems, so it seems like an odd thing to target to "fix".

Comment: Nice question; never thought of it really.

Comment: This came up sporadically for me because my client sometimes submitted JSON data (mutable) and sometimes URL Form Encoded (immutable) messages.

Comment: For non-English speakers, "mutify" isn't a word - the correct phrase is "you can mutate it" or "you can modify it". There's also no need to gender the developers - you could use "Django team" or "core devs" rather than "guys".

Answer (score 136, accepted):

It's a bit of a mystery, isn't it? Several superficially plausible theories turn out to be wrong on investigation:

1. So that the `POST` object doesn't have to implement mutation methods? No: the `POST` object belongs to the [`django.http.QueryDict` class](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/http/__init__.py#L371), which implements a full set of mutation methods including `__setitem__`, `__delitem__`, `pop` and `clear`. It implements immutability by checking a flag when you call one of the mutation methods. And when you call the `copy` method you get another `QueryDict` instance with the mutable flag turned on.
2. For performance improvement? No: the `QueryDict` class gains no performance benefit when the mutable flag is turned off.
3. So that the `POST` object can be used as a dictionary key? No: `QueryDict` objects are not hashable.
4. So that the `POST` data can be built lazily (without committing to read the whole response), [as claimed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339857/why-is-post-data-copied-in-django#comment2312894_2339963)? I see no evidence of this in the code: as far as I can tell, the whole of the response is always read, either [directly](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/http/__init__.py#L296), or via [`MultiPartParser`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/http/multipartparser.py#L35) for `multipart` responses.
5. To protect you against programming errors? I've seen this claimed, but I've never seen a good explanation of what these errors are, and how immutability protects you against them.

In any case, `POST` is *not always immutable*: when the response is `multipart`, then `POST` is mutable. This seems to put the kibosh on most theories you might think of. (Unless this behaviour is an oversight.)

In summary, **I can see no clear rationale** in Django for the `POST` object to be immutable for non-`multipart` requests.

Comment: I've noticed tons of rough edges like this in Django. Must've made sense to somebody at some point, though.

Comment: I found this in another Stack answer: "And it must be immutable so that it can be built lazily. The copy forces getting all the POST data. Until the copy, it may not all be fetched. Further, for a multi-threaded WSGI server to work reasonably well, it's helpful if this is immutable"

Comment: Ah, sorry, I missed that. I only read the question and the first 2 points of your post. Was just trying to be nice and follow up with info I had found elsewhere. Maybe it use to load lazily, but now doesn't and the QueryDict is code that just needs to be replaced? idk.

Comment: @Seaux you shouldn't read SO answers lazily when you intend to comment on them. ;-)

Comment: @ChrisWesseling I see what you did there

Comment: Even better, the querydict is mutable when I send the request suing the django test client.

Answer (score 88):

If the request was the result of a Django **`form`** submission, then it is reasonable for POST being **`immutable`** to ensure the integrity of the data **between** the form **submission** and the form **validation**.  However, if the request was **not** sent via a Django **`form`** submission, then POST is **`mutable`** as there is no form validation.

You can always do something like this: (as per [@leo-the-manic's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12611345/django-why-is-the-request-post-object-immutable#comment31517766_12613004))

```
#  .....
mutable = request.POST._mutable
request.POST._mutable = True
request.POST['some_data'] = 'test data'
request.POST._mutable = mutable
# ......
```

Comment: @JoshK: I guess the commenter wanted to make POST mutable, and the code snippet in this answer helped.

Comment: You can add new key,value but you cant change the existing data.

Comment: Nice. And I'm sure whoever use this code knows what he or she is doing.

Comment: @VamsidharMuggulla Both adding and changing is possible. Even deleting is allowed.

Answer (score 5):

**Update**:

Gareth Rees was right that point 1 & 3 were not valid in this case. Though I think point 2 and 4 are still valid, therefore I will leave theses here.

*(I noticed that the `request.POST` object of both Pyramid(Pylon) and Django is some form of `MultiDict`. So perhaps it is a more common practice than making `request.POST` immutable.)*

---

I can't speak for the Django guys, though it seems to me that it could because of some of these reasons:

1. <strike>**Performence**. immutable objects are "faster" over mutable ones in that they allow substantial optimizations. An object is immutable means that we can allocate space for it at *creation time*, and the space requirements are not changing. It also has things like copy efficiency and comparison efficiency because of it.</strike>  
   **Edit**: this is not the case for `QueryDict` as Gareth Rees pointed out.
2. In the case of `request.POST`, it seems no activity in the server side should need to alter the **request's** data. And hence immutable objects are more suited, not to mention they have substantial performence advantage.
3. <strike>Immutable objects can be used as `dict` keys, which I *suppose* could be very useful somewhere in Django..</strike>  
   **Edit**: my mistake, *immutable* does not directly imply *hashable*; *hashable* objects however, are typically *immutable* as well.
4. When you pass around `request.POST` (especially to third-party plugins and out), you can expect that this request object from the user will remain unchanged.

In some way these reasons are also generic answers to "immutable vs mutable?" question. I am certain there are much more design considerations than above in the Django case.

Comment: The last case is really important. It's really about security. This is why Django provides `sessions` which is short-live way of getting and modifying data between states.

Comment: Your point (1) can't be the answer in this case, because `POST` is a [`QueryDict` object](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/http/__init__.py#L371), and these objects get no performance benefit from being immutable. And your point (3) can't be the answer, because `QueryDict` objects aren't hashable, and so can't used as dictionary keys.

Comment: @GarethRees Thanks for pointing these out. Indeed I was wrong. I updated my answer to correct these. I should have paid more attention to `QueryDict` before I replied.

Comment: @CppLearner The security point seems moot, e.g. `requests.POST._mutable = True; requests.POST['foo'] = 'bar'; request.POST._mutable = False`

Answer (score 4):

I like it being immutable by default. 
As pointed out you can make it mutable if you need to but you must be explicit about it.
It is like 'I know that I can make my form debugging a nightmare but I know what I am doing now.'

Answer (score 2):

I found this in a comment on Stack Answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/2339963

> And it must be immutable so that it can be built lazily. The copy forces getting all the POST data. Until the copy, it may not all be fetched. Further, for a multi-threaded WSGI server to work reasonably well, it's helpful if this is immutable

Answer (score 1):

Please note: `multipart` request are immutable since Django 1.11
https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.11.x/django/http/multipartparser.py#L292

They were mutable in previous versions.

Comment: Also mentioned in Django 1.11 [release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/releases/1.11/#miscellaneous).