# django modifying the request object

Tags: python, django

I already have a django project and it logical like those:

url:    URL?username=name&pwd=passwd

view:

```
def func(request):
   dic = request.GET

   username = dic.get("username")
   pwd = dic.get("pwd")
```

but now we need encrypt the data. Then, the request become this:

url:    URL?crypt=XXXXXXXXXX       (XXXXXXXX is encrypted str for "username=name&pwd=passwd")

so I need modify every view function. But now I want decrypt in django middleware to prevent from modifying every view function.

but when I modify request.GET, I recive error msg "This QueryDict instance is immutable". How can I modify it?

Comment: Sending username and password in the url is a very bad idea.

Comment: Why would you need to send username and password in the url itself?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [django - why is the request.POST object immutable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12611345/django-why-is-the-request-post-object-immutable)

Answer (score 130):

[`django.http.QueryDict`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects) objects that are assigned to `request.GET` and `request.POST` are immutable.

You can convert it to a mutable `QueryDict` instance by copying it:

```
request.GET = request.GET.copy()
```

Afterwards you'll be able to modify the `QueryDict`:

```
>>> from django.test.client import RequestFactory
>>> request = RequestFactory().get('/')
>>> request.GET
<QueryDict: {}>
>>> request.GET['foo'] = 'bar'
AttributeError: This QueryDict instance is immutable
>>> request.GET = request.GET.copy()
<QueryDict: {}>
>>> request.GET['foo'] = 'bar'
>>> request.GET
<QueryDict: {'foo': 'bar'}>
```

This has been purposefully designed so that none of the application components are allowed to edit the source request data, so even creating a immutable `QueryDict` again would break this design. I would still suggest that you follow the guidelines and assign additional request data directly on the `request` object in your middleware, despite the fact that it might cause you to edit your sources.

Comment: In Django 2.0, when I try to do this, I get an AttributeError "can't set attribute"

Answer (score 69):

Remove immutability:

```
if not request.GET._mutable:
   request.GET._mutable = True

# now you can spoil it
request.GET['pwd'] = 'iloveyou'
```

**Update**

The Django sanctioned way is: *request.GET.copy()*.

According to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict):

> The QueryDicts at request.POST and request.GET will be immutable when accessed in a normal request/response cycle. To get a mutable version you need to use QueryDict.copy().

Nothing guarantees future Django versions will use *_mutable*. This has more chances to change than the *copy()* method.

Comment: This is better to avoid the cost associated with copy() on a POST request

Comment: ...but worse because it modifies an internal attribute.

Comment: After setting your value(s) you can just do: `request.GET._mutable = False` to make it unmutable again.

Comment: Please don't recommend doing this.

Comment: can anybody tell me "is this approach secure?"

Comment: at least add a condition `hasattr(request.GET, '_mutable')`. otherwise use `copy()`

Answer (score 9):

You shouldn't use GET to send the username and password, it's bad practice (since it shows the information on the URL bar, and might pose a [security risk](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/12531/ssl-with-get-and-post)). Instead, use POST. Also, I'm guessing you're trying to authenticate your users, and it seems like you're doing too much work (creating a new middleware) to deal with something that is completely built in, to take the example [from the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.login):

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login

def my_view(request):
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            # Redirect to a success page.
        else:
            # Return a 'disabled account' error message
    else:
        # Return an 'invalid login' error message.
```

I myself really like using the [login_required decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.login_required), very simple to use. Hope that helps

Comment: thanks for your answer. that's just a example. We not only use GET but also use POST. Even though use post, we must encrypt the data.Because I'm afraid some tools like 'tcpdump' crawl packet.So, encrypt/decrypt is necessary.The question Confusing me is how can I modify view function as less as possible. So I want use middleware

Comment: Look into the documentation about creating your own middleware. You want to use process_request or process_view, but keep in mind that accessing the request.POST inside those would cause the view not to run (csrf is an exception to that rule, so look into how it works to figure how to write your own) https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/

Comment: Also, not sure how much that is relevant but take a look at this: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-secure

Comment: There is no security problem with GET request per se.  It's kind of bad practice because they're in the address bar ... but I just want to make sure that everybody is clear that over HTTPS, GET and POST payloads are equally protected in transit.  Via HTTP, they are equally unprotected.

Comment: @AdamNelson You're not entirely correct, but I revised my answer to be more accurate nonetheless

Comment: @AdamNelson if you pass anything into a GET request then it becomes available in log files, internet history, and the redirect HTTP header. It's not secure at all, even over HTTPS. They are not equally protected in transit.

Comment: @Jordan the log file and Internet history parts are legitimate side channel attacks and you're right that they make GET worse than POST for security, but the protection inside the HTTPS envelope is exactly the same whether it's POST or GET

Answer (score 4):

```
request.GET._mutable = True
```

you need this.

```
def func(request):
   dic = request.GET
   request.GET._mutable = True #to make it editable 
   username = dic.get("username")
   request.GET.pop("pwd")
   request.GET._mutable = False #make it False once edit done
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to change the request.data:

```
def func(request):
   request.data._mutable = True
   dic = request.data
   username = dic['username']
   pwd = dic['pwd']
```