# change request.GET QueryDict values

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I want to change `request.GET` querydict object in django. I tried this but changes made by me are not reflected. I tried this

```
tempdict = self.request.GET.copy() # Empty initially
tempdict['state'] = ['XYZ',]
tempdict['ajaxtype'] = ['facet',]
print self.request.GET
```

I get

```
<QueryDict: {}> as my output
```

Is it possible to change the `request.GET` querydict object in django?

Comment: Why do you want to change `request.GET`?

Comment: I have to categorize the input text entered by the user and then pass it to another function which uses request.GET qurydict to do further processing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [django modifying the request object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18930234/django-modifying-the-request-object)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [django - why is the request.POST object immutable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12611345/django-why-is-the-request-post-object-immutable)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can't change the `request.GET` or `request.POST` as they are instances of `QueryDict` which are [immutable according to the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects):

> QueryDict instances are immutable, unless you create a copy() of them. That means you can’t change attributes of request.POST and request.GET directly.

Answer (score 10):

Your code should work if you add one little step: you are now making a copy of the `request.GET`, but you have not assigned it back to the `request`. So it is just a standalone object which is not related to the `request` in any way.

This would the the necessary improvement:

```py
tempdict = self.request.GET.copy()
tempdict['state'] = ['XYZ',]
tempdict['ajaxtype'] = ['facet',]
self.request.GET = tempdict  # this is the added line
print(self.request.GET)
```

I have tested it in writing custom middleware, but I assume it works the same way in all places.