# Django rest framework custom filter for POST request

Tags: python, django, post, filter, django-rest-framework

In filters.py, I have a `CustomFilter` defined that has values of type `ComboSortFilter` and `IntegerListFilter`.

In views.py, I defined a ViewSet that has `filter_class = CustomFilter` and this works great for `GET` requests, using query-string params in the url, that get processed using the custom filtering.

I also need to support `POST` requests, because some of the filter criteria is too long to put in the URL.

So I added a `post` method to my ViewSet where I pull the params from `request.DATA` then filter, serialize and paginate them...

in my ViewSet's post method in views.py:

```
queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(**filter_args)
page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
serializer = self.get_pagination_serializer(page)
return Response(serializer.data)
```

For simple filtering the above works fine. However, the filtering that I have defined in my `CustomFilter` that filters fields using `ComboSortFilter` and `IntegerListFilter` is a bit more complex:

in filters.py:

```
class IntegerListFilter(django_filters.Filter):
    def filter(self, qs, value):
        if value not in (None, ''):
            integers = [int(v) for v in value.split(',')]
            return qs.filter(**{'{0}__{1}'.format(self.name, self.lookup_type): integers})
        return qs

class ComboSortFilter(django_filters.Filter):
    def __init__(self, threshold, lookup_type, order='ASC'):
        super(ComboSortFilter, self).__init__(lookup_type=lookup_type)
        self.threshold = threshold
        self.order = order

    def filter(self, qs, value):
        if value not in (None, ''):
            fields = [str(v) for v in value.split(',')]
            for field in fields:  # filters each field's values relative to threshold
                qs = qs.filter(**{'{0}__{1}'.format(field, self.lookup_type): self.threshold})
            if self.order == 'DESC':
                fields = ['-{0}'.format(f) for f in fields]
            qs = qs.order_by(*fields)
        return qs

class CustomFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    thing_ids = IntegerListFilter(name="thing_id", lookup_type='in')
    sort_desc = ComboSortFilter(lookup_type='gte', threshold=100, order='DESC')
    sort_asc = ComboSortFilter(lookup_type='lte', threshold=100)
```

Is there any way to reference the `CustomFilter` FilterSet or either of my two custom filters from within the ViewSet's post method? I would hate to have to duplicate all this filtering code in `views.py` to get it to work.

All the documentation on [Django-rest-framework:filters](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/) only includes simple examples either rolling your own in the views, or using a filter class. Is there a way to call a filter class directly from a view, overriding the values it normally gets from the querystrings?

Answer (score 10):

figured it out:

```
class MyPostViewSet(BaseModelViewSet):

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.queryset
        filter_params = request.DATA or request.GET
        if filter_params:
            queryfilter = self.filter_class(filter_params, queryset=queryset)
            queryset = queryfilter.qs
        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        serializer = self.get_pagination_serializer(page)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: Using Django 1.11, DRF 3.9.0: pagination doesn't work because DRF checks `request.query_params`. It might be possible to manually set the query params, but this needs a separate workaround like mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18930234/django-modifying-the-request-object