# Use filterset class in a nested route in Django REST Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

We have a REST API created with Django and Django REST Framework. With the package `django-filter` I've created a FilterSet class which I want to use in a nested route.

For illustration, we have model classes **User**, **Post**, **Tag**. A **Post** has one author (**User**) and can have many (or none) **Tags**.

The following endpoints are present:

- /users/[id]/
- /posts/[id]/
- /users/[id]/posts/

The FilterSet class looks like this:

```
class PostFilterSet(filters.FilterSet):
    tags = filters.ModelChoiceFilter(queryset=Tag.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ("tags",)
```

We use it in the viewset for Posts:

```
class PostViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    filter_backends = [filters.DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_class = PostFilterSet
```

Now this is working well and the list of posts can be filtered by tag, like this:

```
/posts/?tags=some_tag
```

In the `UserViewSet` we have a nested route created with the decorator action:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    filter_backends = [filters.DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_class = UserFilterSet

    @action(methods=["get"], detail=True)
    def posts(self, request, pk):
        # logic to fetch posts for the given user
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

We want to filter the list of posts for a given user (author) tagged by some tag:

```
/users/[id]/posts/?tags=some_tag
```

I want to use the `PostFilterSet` class in the nested route above. Is this possible? If yes, how should it be done?

Comment: add "url_path" and "url_name" in "action"    @action(methods=["get"], detail=True, url_path="posts/", url_name="ufposts")

Comment: @NarcisseDoudieuSiewe thanks for your comment. I have added `url_name` and `url_path`, but this doesn't do anything about the filters.

Comment: but did you set filter_backends, filter_backends, serializer_class and queryset accordingly for UserViewSet?

Comment: Those are set for `UserViewSet`. The problem is how to set `PostFilterSet` defined for model `Post` in the `UserViewSet` to apply filters to the nested route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I have solved this problem:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    filter_backends = [filters.DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_class = UserFilterSet

    @action(methods=["get"], detail=True)
    def posts(self, request, pk):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=pk)
        posts = Post.objects.filter(author=user)
        filter_class = PostFilterSet(request.query_params, queryset=posts)
        posts = filter_class.qs
        serializer = PostSerializer(posts, many=True, context={"request": request})
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

The bold lines are showing how to call the filterset class manually and filter the queryset.

Now if the client calls the endpoint like this:

```
/users/[id]/posts/?tags=some_tag
```

then the query parameters (in this case it's only one - **tags**) will be used to filter the queryset.

This answer gave me an idea:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27161942/3848833

If you have implemented pagination then this isn't going to work straightforward and you'll have to adjust the code.