# Nesting APIView breaks request if request.FILES property is called

Tags: django, debugging, request, django-rest-framework

We have an `APIView` (`FooView`) that can be accessed directly through a URL.

We have another `APIView` `APIKeyImportView` that will reuse `FooView` depending of file name (it is done this way for compatibility with an API).

However when `request.FILES` is accessed from `APIKeyImportView` to look at the file names, `request.FILES` becomes empty in `FooView`.

It appears that accessing `request.FILES` will makes it un-useable by the nested view.

Is there a way around this?

```
  class FooView(APIView):
      permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

      def post(self, request, vendor):
          file = request.FILES.get('file')
          if not file:
              return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
          return Response()


  class APIKeyImportView(APIView):
      permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
      authentication_classes = (ApiKeyAuthentication,)

      def post(self, request):
          file = request.FILES.get('file')
          if not file:
              return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
          name = file.name

          if name.startswith('FOO'):
              return FooView.as_view()(request=request)
          else:
              return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Removing the validation on `request.Files` in `APIKeyImportView` will make it accessible in `FooView` but it kinds of miss the point.

Inspecting `request` in PyCharm will also make it un-useable in `FooView` since the debugger will call the properties.

```
  class APIKeyImportView(APIView):
      permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
      authentication_classes = (ApiKeyAuthentication,)

      def post(self, request):
          return FooView.as_view()(request=request)
```

These solutions are not working:

[django modifying the request object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18930234/django-modifying-the-request-object)

Tested on the following versions:

- Django 1.9.5
- django-rest-framework 3.3.3
- Python 3.4.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround I found was to pass `request.FILES` but I am not sure if it has side effects

```
  class FooView(APIView):
      permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

      _files = None

      @property
      def request_files(self):
          if self._files:
              return self._files
          return self.request.FILES

      def post(self, request, vendor):
          file = self.request_files.get('file')
          if not file:
              return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
          return Response()


  class APIKeyImportView(APIView):
      permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
      authentication_classes = (ApiKeyAuthentication,)

      def post(self, request):
          file = request.FILES.get('file')
          if not file:
              return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
          name = file.name

          if name.startswith('FOO'):
              # Passing FILES here
              return FooView.as_view(_files=request.FILES)(request=request)
          else:
              return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```