# how to alter/change the post data in django UpdateView

Tags: django, post, request, django-class-based-views

I am using django update view for my `model/records` editing stuff like below

```
class EditProductView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Product
    def get_template_names(self):

        return ['website/product/edit_product.html']

    def get_success_url(self):

        return reverse('product_details', args=[self.kwargs['pk']])

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        publisher = Publisher.objects.get(product__id=self.kwargs['pk']) 
        context = super(EditProductView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update(
           {
            'publisher':publisher,
            }
          )
        return context        

edit_product =  EditProductView.as_view()
```

So what all i want/trying to do is alter(add some data, edit already submitted data according to website functionality) the `POST` data before submitting to form,

So i know that `UpdateView` has some method def `def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):` , but i dont know exactly how to use it

Suppose below is the request.POST data i am getting

```
<QueryDict: {u'product_name': [u'Biscuit'], u'product_price': [u'1000'], u'product_tag': [u'']}>
```

So now i want to alter the above `QueryDict` and if the value of `product_tag` was empty i need assign some default one and submit with latest querdict

Also i know that Querydict is mutable, but because of sure i need to edit the POST data, before `submitting/saving to database`, i need to make that querydict as dict, then edit it, and convert back to querdict

So after all whats my question is

1. How can we alter the `POST` data in `UpdateView` before submitting/saving to database
2. Is the `post` method heplful?

Answer (score 13):

The `QueryDict` is mutable after you create its `.copy()`. See the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict).

**Update** Example:

```
class SomeUpdateView(UpdateView):

    def post(self, request, **kwargs):
        request.POST = request.POST.copy()
        request.POST['some_key'] = 'some_value'
        return super(SomeUpdateView, self).post(request, **kwargs)
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12611345/django-why-is-the-request-post-object-immutable) is much broader discussion about the topic.

Furthermore, shouldn't this be done in `ModelForm` subclass? You're certainly aware you can set custom form as a `form_class` in `UpdateView`. Such a logic usually needs unit tests and it's much easier to unit test logic which sits in the form.

Comment: actually, i just want don't want to use the ModelForm as already facing some issues with ModelForms in my case. So finally can we edit the post data in the UpdateView above ?

Comment: k that was helpful, but what if i need to replace the request.POST with entire new querydict ? Is there any way to replace request.POST with entire new querydict ? like request.POST = new_querdict

Comment: Yeah. `request.POST = QueryDict()`. :)

Comment: I'm using `form_valid`. What do I do?