# Loop through form POST store data in python variable

Tags: python, django

I have a form that holds multiple inputs... Within the `request.POST`, I'm looping through all of the input values. But I'd like to store them within a variable.. How do I do that?

```
for key, value in request.POST.items():
   print(key, value)  # how can I store instead of print?
```

How can I store all values in a python array/dict/whatever?

Comment: You mentioned you had a form, so I would imagine it's a lot easier to loop on the form field instead. Are you aware of that?

Comment: @ShangWang No. Love to try it. How can I loop through form fields and store the data?

Comment: Why you don't do this `mydict = request.POST`? or `mydict = request.POST.copy()`

Comment: what is .copy() ?@trinchet

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12611345/django-why-is-the-request-post-object-immutable

Comment: `request.POST` is itself a dict. `request.POST.items()` is itself a list of tuples. It is unnecessary to use a for-loop here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have couple of ways to store the POST data in a local variable. The question is: why would you want to do that when you have access to `request.POST` anyway?

```
# Note: all keys and values in these structures are strings

# easiest, but immutable QueryDict
d = request.POST 

# dict 
d = dict(request.POST.items())

# array
a = list(request.POST.items())  # list of key-value tuples
a = request.POST.values()  # list of values only
```

These variables will only live for the current request-response cycle. If you want to persist any of the data beyond that, you would have to store them to the database. Moreover, I recommend using a [django form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/) to handle POST data. That will take care of validation, type-casting, etc. for you.

Comment: Awesome. To answer your question, I'm using request.POST to get some data to send to an api.

Comment: I come from a javascript background, is there such thing as objects? Like could I store all the values in an object?

Comment: Does .values() include hidden inputs? (I'd like to avoid hidden inputs if possible)

Comment: Everything in Python is an object. A `dict` is most easily converted to JSON string via `json.dumps(d)`. `.values()` does include hidden inputs!

Comment: How can I avoid hidden inputs?

Answer (score 0):

This might not directly answer your question, but I don't recommend accessing `request.POST` directly since you already had a form. Form is good that it abstracts away a lot of the raw data that you need to handle by encapsulating them in the form object, so I would suggest check the form itself for data:

```
form = YourForm(request.POST or None)
if form.is_valid():
    field1_value = form.cleaned_data['field1']
    field2_value = form.cleaned_data['field2']
```

django doc has examples about [how to access form fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/#field-data) like I did.

Also, if you want to get a copy of mutable dict object same as `request.POST`, you could do:

```
post_copy = request.POST.copy()
```

Comment: The reason why I have a form is because I'm grabbing data from the form and sending to an API. it was the best way I could think of.

Comment: That's totally a good way of doing it, I'm just suggesting using form to fetch data instead of accessing raw data from `request.POST` which could be very painful.

Comment: So i come from a js background, is a dict an object? Like if I sent the json string, would it appear like a js object?

Comment: In python dict is an object, everything is an object in python. If you have a json string in python, you need to do `json.loads(json_string)` to convert json string to python dict(like a hash in js).https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

Comment: If you want to send a python dict to the template and be understood by js, it's the other way round: `json.dumps(dict)`, or just use a shortcut `JSONResponse` in django: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects

Comment: Any idea on how to avoid hidden inputs being placed within dict?

Comment: Just get the whole dict and manually get rid of the entries that are hidden: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844672/delete-an-element-from-a-dictionary