# How to serialize data not coming from the request and properly validate it (ModelSerializer in Django Rest Framework)?

Tags: django, validation, serialization, django-rest-framework

Using Django Rest Framework 3, Function Based Views, and the ModelSerializer (more specifically the HyperlinkedModelSerializer).

When a user submits a form from the client, I have a view that takes the request data, uses it to call to an external API, then uses the data from the external API to populate data for a model serializer.
 I *believe* I have this part working properly, and from what I read, you are supposed to use **context** and **validate()**

In my model serializer, I have so far just this one overidden function:

```
from django.core.validators import URLValidator

def validate(self, data):
    if 'foo_url' in self.context:
        data['foo_url'] = self.context['foo_url']
        URLValidator(data['foo_url'])
    if 'bar_url' in self.context:
        data['bar_url'] = self.context['bar_url']
        URLValidator(data['bar_url'])
    return super(SomeSerializer, self).validate(data)
```

Just in case, the relevant view code is like so:

```
context = {'request': request}
...
context['foo_url'] = foo_url
context['bar_url'] = bar_url
s = SomeSerializer(data=request.data, context=context)
if s.is_valid():
    s.save(user=request.user)
    return Response(s.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Now assuming I have the right idea going (my model does populate its `foo_url` and `bar_url` fields from the corresponding context data), where I get confused is how the validation is not working.  If I give it bad data, the model serializer does not reject it.

I assumed that in `validate()`, by adding the context data to the data, the data would be checked for validity when `is_valid()` was called.  Maybe not the case, especially when I print out `s` (after using the serializer but before calling `is_valid()`) there is no indication that the request object's `data` has been populated with the context data from `validate()` (I don't know if it should be).

So I tried calling the URLValidators directly in the `validate()` method, but still doesn't seem to be working.  No errors despite giving it invalid data like 'asdf' or an empty python dict ({}).  My test assertions show that the field indeed contains invalid data like '{}'.

What would be the proper way to do this?

Comment: I also don't understand how this also manages to make it past the Django's model validation, since 'asdf' or '{}' are not valid URLField data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not calling the validator.

By doing `URLValidator(data['bar_url'])` you're actually building an url validator with custom schemes [(see the docs)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/validators/#urlvalidator) and that's it. The proper code should be:

```
URLValidator()(data['bar_url'])
```

Where you build a default url validator and then validate the value.

---

But anyway I would not use this approach, what I would do instead is directly add the extra data (not using the context) and let DRF do the validation by declaring the right fields:

```
# Somewhere in your view
request.data['bar_url'] = 'some_url'

# In serializer:
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    bar_url = serializers.URLField()

    class Meta:
        fields = ('bar_url', ...)
```

---

To answer your comment

> I also don't understand how this also manages to make it past the
>   Django's model validation

See this answer:
[Why doesn't django's model.save() call full_clean()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441539/why-doesnt-djangos-model-save-call-full-clean)

By default Django does not automatically call the `.full_clean` method so you can save a model instance with invalid values (unless the constraints are on the database level).

Comment: Thank you so much, seems like I misread the docs.  I thought request.data was inaccessible until after you called is_valid() (sort of like Django form data).  I assume Django makes its form data immutable before validation for a reason.  Is it generally OK to edit the request data like this?

Comment: Well, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12611345/django-why-is-the-request-post-object-immutable) it is explained that there's no strong reasons for the request to be immutable. Personally I think it's ok to add data to the request like that, so that the serialization process can stay the same.