# data._mutable= True in Django rest framework

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework, immutability, mutable

I have seen this many times and looked it everywhere but couldn't figure out what it actually means and is it mandatory? I have not used this `data._mutable = True or False` in my code before and I am not sure whether I should be using it or not.

The code snippet looks somewhat like this.

```
def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = self.get_object()
        data = request.data
        if data.get("something") == "null":
            data._mutable = True
            data["something"] = None
            data._mutable = False
```

Why do we need to assign True or False to the private attribute _mutable of data object.??

Comment: Otherwise you can not set `data['something'] = None`: by default `request.data` is immutable, and thus does not accept altering the data.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [django - why is the request.POST object immutable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12611345/django-why-is-the-request-post-object-immutable)

Comment: This is also mostly an opinion question.  You shouldn't ever need to use it outside of exceedingly rare circumstances, so just ignore it.  Pass your data to a serializer and validate it, and mutate it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use as parser a [**`FormParser`** <sup>[drf-doc]</sup>](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/#formparser) or [**`MultiPartParser`** <sup>[drf-doc]</sup>](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/#multipartparser), or another parser that parses to a [**`QueryDict`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict), then the `QueryDict` is by default *immutable*. That means that it will reject any changes to it, so you can not add, remove or edit key-value pairs.

By setting the `._mutable` attribute, you can prevent this from raising errors, and thus mutate the `QueryDict`. But it is not good practice, since it is not documented that you can make the `QueryDict` mutable by setting the `._mutable` attribute to `True`. Usually you work with [**`.copy()`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.copy) which will return a *mutable* deep copy, so:

```
def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = self.get_object()
        data = request.data
        if data.get('something') == 'null':
            data = data.copy()
            data['something'] = None
        # …
```

Comment: Isn't having null as a value or None the same thing? I don't see any cases where there is a need to convert null to None.

Comment: @Reactoo: that depends on the handler of the data. There can be cases where `null` needs to be converted to `None`, although for an effective serializer, that is probably indeed not the case.

Comment: @Williem , Can you help me on this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69770813/use-of-same-serializer-class-for-post-and-get-request-in-django-rest-framework